# Jquery Output Odd Numbers skip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My function has an input and 2 outputs. It always has to start with a minimum input of 5, and that one needs to give me 3&4 in the outputs. and 6 gives 4&5. It also skips the odd numbers(it keeps the value of the last output when you give an odd number).

Only somewhere my code goes wrong. Because the function i need to replicate for example gives 53&54 as output when you put in 100. And mine just does -1 and -2 on the 100 so i get 98&97.

also i want 5 to give 3&4 and then when you put in 6 it needs to give 4&5, only i cant give it a value without 6 being NaN or 3&4 aswell.

This is what i need to **duplicate** (enter 5 in the left input field): https://www.schuttinggigant.com/

**GIF** of the function here: https://gyazo.com/6a65b65ee5bedddfe35851f78aa8dc27

**My html:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="InputField InputMeters">
  <input type="tel" name="iFenceMeters" id="FenceMeters" class="AutosubmitCalculator calcTotal" data-minimum-length="1" tabindex="1" placeholder="00" maxlength="3" value="" />
  <div class="FormExclamation Tipped Hidden" id="FormCalculatorExclamationFence">0</div>
</div>
Output:

<div class="SummaryRow">
  <strong>Schermen</strong>
  <input name="schermentotaal" type="text" id="schermentotaal" readonly="readonly" value="" />
</div>

<div class="SummaryRow">
  <strong>Palen en onderplaten</strong>
  <input name="schermentotaal2" type="text" id="schermentotaal2" readonly="readonly" value="" />
</div>
```

**My Jquery:**

```
 $(".calcTotal").on('input', function(elem) {
   let num = $(this).val();
   if (num % 2 !== 0) {
     num--;
   }


   $("#schermentotaal").val(num - 2);
   $("#schermentotaal2").val(num - 1);
 });
```

**Update:** I dont know how but MAYBE instead of -1 and -2 i need to do something procentages? - x%. just an idea.

Comment: Is this a homework question?  A *very* similar question was asked yesterday.  Also, your requirement/expected results need more definition, eg "*keeps the value of the last number(an even number)*" - implies the last entered number, not the number below (*keeps*) so if I enter 6 then 101 it would give the result of 6.  Is this intended?

Comment: Ye sorry for my bad explanation. Im not that fluent in english. But I'm trying hard. And no if you would be to enter 6 you get 4&5 and when you give it 100 after that it just has to show 53&54 like i said in the question. (100 is the limit after that my site says a limit has been reached.)

Comment: Why should 100 go to 53 and 54 nd not 98 and 99 ? ( what is the rule that controls this)

Comment: This is the last part i need to complete for my internship function. But this is something i dont know either. I have tried alot of stuff and nothing works, or only works half. I know that the site show the value of the past even if you give it an odd number. and it keeps counting up from the first even. So that would be from 6. So eventually if you give it 100, its at 53&54. And not 98&99, because it doesnt count up from the even you put in last.

Comment: It **clearly** not "taking even number below odd number" as can be tested with 10/50/100 or any value > 6 or 7.   So you need to work out **exactly what it is doing first**.   Your question asks how to get even number below entered odd number - but your results don't match this question, so you fail any valid answers.  This is called an XY Problem - your asking how to solve X when Y is the actual problem.  It might be partly a language issue, but mostly it's an understanding of the problem issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're subtracting from `num` too many times when you're updating the HTML. Change your function to this:

```
$(".calcTotal").on('input', function() {
    let num = $(this).val();
    if (num % 2 === 0) {
        num--;
    }
    $("#schermentotaal").val(num - 1);
    $("#schermentotaal2").val(num);
});
```

All I changed was the last two lines, in case you're wondering.

Comment: 5 needs to be 3 & 4. And as you can see in the GIF 6 has to be at 4&5. Should i add a static value for that?|

GIF: https://gyazo.com/9c9ff1768f866606f564556707e31526
The numbers are off. Because the function i need to replicate keeps counting in +1 and +2 from the last output they had from an even input.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".calcTotal").on('input', function(elem) {
   let num = $(this).val();
   if (num % 2 === 0 && num > 2) { // why num>2 because num-2 will be 0 and you don't wont to display 0 
       $("#schermentotaal").val(num - 2);
       $("#schermentotaal2").val(num - 1);
   }
});
```